# Android / SQL Server: Set Text to "No time" if the data at database is NULL

Tags: java, android, sql-server, android-studio

at my database table, there's a column name "time_photo_before". The column automatically set to NULL if there's no data.

At android, I got a problem. Although I set the text to "No time" when the data is null, but it still appears the next "null" at the TextView. But if there's a data, the data will display. Below is my code:

```
    timePhotoBefore = findViewById(R.id.timePhotoBefore);

    if(taskClass.getTime_photo_before() != null ){
        timePhotoBefore.setText(taskClass.getTime_photo_before());

    }else {
        timePhotoBefore.setText("No time");
    }
```

Can I know what is the problem?

Comment: setText("No time"). You missed the 2nd "

Comment: You can try https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: @DominikWuttke already change. but still same

Comment: @sadat, can you edit my code. I didnt understand

Comment: if(textUtils.isEmpty(taskClass.getTime_photo_before()){ ...... }else {.....}, alternatively check if the text is really text "null" or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write like this!

```
timePhotoBefore = findViewById(R.id.timePhotoBefore);

    if(taskClass.getTime_photo_before() != null )
    {
        timePhotoBefore.setText(taskClass.getTime_photo_before());
        if (timePhotoBefore.getText().equals("NULL")
            timePhotoBefore.setText("No Time");
    }
    else
    {
        timePhotoBefore.setText("No time");
    }
```